# Designing a grid layout fo android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

for a project i have designed a custom gridview.. now i want in a specific form

[image]

as u can see the rows are alternating. as this is dynamic, i will have "x" number of rows. any suggestions on how i can proceed on this? I have done grid view b4 but then all squares are consistent. What to do when rows have specific sizes?

Between can i use a list view? i have 2 items per grid/square to display..

Thanks in advance..

My grid layout

```
 <FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" />
```

my grid view item

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:padding="1dp">
<org.qui.osamp.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#55000000"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVPlusButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plusbutton3" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Plz show the xml definition for the gridview.

Comment: You can go for a listview and manage custom sizes within the getView method of the listview adapter. If you need more control, you can go for linearlayouts for each row (loaded dynamically) within a scrollview container.

Comment: @Srikanth i have added a grid view code... and on the listview since this is  a dynamic project i will be accepting the values from server and wont the array list have to return 2 rows as 1 row since there are 2 squares in 1 row? is that correct coding?

Comment: Once you receive data from the server, determine the grouping. For example, suppose ArrayList item 1 & 2 are to be displayed in listview's 5th row, in getView method of adapter, for the 5th row, add values 1 & 2 and call notifydatasetchanged method to refresh the view. If you need to add arraylist item 5, add item 5 in the same way. The listview row is a container that accepts the data dynamically & displays within bounds defined by the view you just added.

Comment: @Srikanth thanks. can i get back to you if i have more queries?

Comment: Ya sure. You can post a comment here, if you need me.